# How to find similar predicted x between 2 models?

Tags: python, model, confusion-matrix, venn-diagram

I have 2 models implemented with the same algorithm but with different number of features thus 2 different confusion matrix.
I would like to see which predicted items are similar between those 2 and plot the similarity predicted in a Venn diagram.

Comment: make a dataframe with an output column for predictions for each model, then add a column with the condition if Pred1==Pred2 => 1 else 0 . now you can count the number of similar results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Answer***

```
data = {"Mod1":[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],"Mod2":[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Similar"] = np.where(df["Mod1"]==df["Mod2"],1,0)
df.head()

#output

Mod1Mod2Similar
0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1
2   1   1   1
3   1   0   0
4   0   1   0
```

This should do the job
***Visualization***

```
# !pip install matplotlib-venn

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2

venn2(subsets = (3, 3, 7), set_labels = ('Mod1', 'Mod2'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the first part is very helpful. However, I am a little bit confused on how to plot the similarity using the Venn diagram as it a set of 1 and 0.

Comment: subsets=(diff_mod1,diff_mod2,intersection). Since you have similar number, count the 1s you will get the intersection number and for the len(data)-intersection = diff_mo1

Comment: @gg1 since the 2 datasets are of the same size, Mod2=Mod1 = count of 1+ count of 0s

Comment: Could you help with the Venn diagram using the sample data you provided in the first part of your answer ? Thanks

Comment: `df["Similar"].value_counts()` `subset(valuefor0,valuefor0,valuefor1)`